# How to store SharePoint survey responses to list using JSOM?

Tags: development, web-part, jsom, survey, survey-list

I have created the SharePoint survey list and I have displayed the survey questions by using programmatically in JSOM. so I need to store the responses in survey list manually using JSOM or C#, Please Suggest me an idea to achieve this

Comment: Share your snippets here how you are retrieving it and where you want to store it?

Comment: i have the survey list name , question name, and answers.in case how to store the response to survey list using JSOM ? . @InnovaITveSolutions